# Where is the guest user for communities

Tags: community, guest-user, user-registration

I want to setup a self-register process for a community. For that I need a guest user. Normally when a community is created with the wizard automatically a guest user is generated. But I don't see the guest user in the system (under manage users) or the guest profile after creating a community. I installed the community with all communities -> new community and then I followed the steps from the wizard.
How can I get a guest user? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Build` -> `Develop` -> `Sites`, click on your `Site/Community` name and click on `Public Access Settings` button.

It would open up the Profile for guest user. And in this page if you click View users, it shows Guest User.

You can configure your custom self register page in Guest user profile, by adding it to *Enabled Visualforce Page Access* related list.

---

Adding more details:
From the [documentation](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/16/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf):

**Can I use the same domain name for my Force.com Sites and my Communities?**

> No, you can’t use the same domain name. Force.com Sites and
>   Communities must each use a unique domain name. If you’re using a
>   domain name for your Force.com site and you want to use it for your
>   communities instead, contact Salesforce Support for assistance with
>   renaming the domain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I go to Sites, now I have to register my domain first. But I already have a domain for my community. Do I have to register a domain again? Actually my existing community is not listed.

Comment: Updated answer, you need to register for Force.com Sites domain as well!